# How to export all events data from Firebase to BigQuery?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I recently integrated BigQuery to my Firebase project and selected to share the Google Analytics data to BigQuery.

I've selected to send my production app's data on a daily basis.

How do I export ALL my Firebase events data from the last 5 years to BigQuery? Currently I only see data from the last 4 days.

This is my integration setting:

[image]

And here is what I see in filters in BigQuery:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Firebase will only write to BigQuery that it receives from the moment you enable the integration. It won't write historical data.

You try to use Analytics Data API to get Google Analytics 4 (GA4) report data: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1
Here the list of dimensions and metrics supported in the Analytics Data API queries: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema

Comment: I see. Thats very unfortunate. So there's no way to import historical data from Firebase in order to analyse it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Its unfortunate about no historical data part, but I guess I'll have to work with the data I have. Also, I briefly looked into the Google Analytics Data API and it seems a lot of code will have to be written and queries for each event which I log will have to be made in order to create the same raw dataset. Also, GA seems to only store the last 90 days or so of data.

Comment: Yes, automatic export is the best solution. Unfortunately, as with Universal Analytics, when this is not present for historical data the only alternative is the API (with the due limits on exported data).

Comment: True. However, the GA API does provide many useful pieces of information on DAU, MAU etc so perhaps my overall analytics strategy should include both running queries on the raw data from BigQuery + using data from GA API to understand user behaviour and app performance.